# How to generate a password which complies with auth validators in Django?

Tags: django, authentication, passwords

I used `User.objects.make_random_password()` to generate passwords for **new** users, however I found out that this method was creating passwords which didn't comply with the validators (AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS) that are configured in Django.

I also tried with `from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password`, but the hashed password does not match all the password validation criteria because is too long.

I want to know if there is a function which creates passwords based on AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS?.

Comment: Can you show your code in which you use `make_random_password`?

Comment: `password = User.objects.make_random_password()`
`validate_password(password)`

The validation sometimes raises the ValidationError, because the generated password doesn't comply with configured validators. Even if you set the length and allowed_chars parameters, then there is no guarantee that it meets the criteria to be a valid password. @BartoszStasiak

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should try to create your own password creator.

Try this function I made for you to create new passwords.

```py
import random 
def create_new_password():
    alphas = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    alphas_cap = alphas.upper()
    numbers = "12345678901234567890123456"
    special_chars = "!@#$%^&*()_+/!@#$%^&*()_+/"
    password_characters = [alphas , alphas_cap , numbers , special_chars ]
    new_password = ""
    for i in range(16) : 
        n = random.randint(0,3)
        chars_used = password_characters[n]
        char = chars_used[random.randint(0,25)]
        new_password += char
    return new_password
print(create_new_password())
```

Comment: This approach still needs to be aware of the configured validators in order to properly create a password.

Comment: what you could do is that configure 4 places for one of each kind of character. One for alpha , capital alpha , special and numeric. Rest you can get there . Or create a flag for checking if all of the chars are there or not .